# How to add AMS codes, Key words

Tags: amsmath

Can some one suggest me how to add AMS codes and Key words for the following  code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\title{Something}
\author{Someone} 

\begin{document}
    \today
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract} 

\maketitle 
%\tableofcontents 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add some more explanation to your question what you mean by "AMS codes" and what kind of keywords you have in mind? Perhaps add some example input and output for illustration.

Comment: @KJO I am sorry if my question was not clear.. I want to ask **how** to add AMS classification.. I know that it is present in that site...

Comment: @KJO I did not understand what it mean to say a library system.. Can you suggest a place where I can read about AMS classification and how it works.. ( not Wikipedia page :))

Comment: The commands you are looking for are `\subjscheme[2010]` and `\keywords`.  This information must appear before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use `\keywords{...}` and `\subjclass{...}` before `\maketitle`.

I reorganized your preamble to make it more consistent. You should be more careful about the order of packages and declarations; as it stood, the preamble was confusing and difficult to maintain.

A `\theoremstyle` declaration remains in force until countermanded by another one, so you don't need to repeat it over and over again.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\setlength{\textheight}{9.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\calclayout

% metadata

\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Some text for the abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Keyword 1, keyword 2}

\subjclass{12X20, 13Y21}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

In order to produce the picture I reduced the text height.

[image]

Comment: This is more than what I can ask. :) thanks.. I think using \subjscheme[2010] make 1991 to 2010...

Comment: I do not know remember why I added “\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}”.. is it absolutely not necessary for anything.. ??

Comment: I do not know how you reduced font.. CAn you please tell me how to get my old font size? I also have written "\setlength{\textheight}{9.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}" but font is small in my file